# How to display custom selected text options in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-phone

When selecting text almost anywhere in the system (Windows Phone) where text can be selected a little pop-up is displayed. How can I make a custom one to display whenever text is selected in an edit control (i.e. TextBox or RichEditBox) inside my app?

EDIT:
What I would like to achieve is something like this: [image: this]

Image is from Android but it represents perfectly what I would like to achieve but, of course, with my custom commands.

Comment: What pop up are you talking about? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @AVKNaidu, I've edited the post with an image.